# Is a novice question on a specific printer allowed?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I was curious if the da Vinci 1.0 AiO printer could print very small objects, like insects, nuts, or any other small object without a flat surface and additionally, if it could print the entire top and bottom of the object. I would not think I would be able to print the bottom features, since the printer had a rotating dish where the lasers would not be able to be scan.  (About the size of 1 -2 cubic centimeters) And if so, then if that question would be appropriate to ask in the beta forum?

The reason I ask is someone asked me if it was able to, but I have not been able to access the actual 3-D printer for use at this time, just manuals which I have looked through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that technical questions or specification questions are appropriate, which is what I take away from your question(s). Questions that I think most users will consider "off-topic" or "out of scope" would be questions such as "Is the daVinci 1.0 AiO a good printer?" as this would be primarily opinion based.

However, by providing more detail about your objective (ie. a focus on smaller, obscure prints) you can get closer to "on-topic". I think if you titled your question along the lines of "How small can I expect the daVinci 1.0 AiO to print?" and elaborating on your specific needs in the bulk of the question could directly answer your question while upholding the values of the community and may possibly lead to suggestions to other machines/processes.